# Self-Hosted agent private network DevOps connectivity issue

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-virtual-network, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am running a container instance in a private network as self-hosted agent to perform DevOps pipeline jobs. The container instance resides in vnet-a and all traffic to the internet is routed via a firewall instance in vnet-b: [image: simplified network design]

If I start the container instance, it displays the logging `[1;36m1. Determining matching Azure Pipelines agent...[0m`. This indicates that it can't connect to the Azure DevOps server.

On the container instance, I opened outbound TCP ports 443 and 80. Furthermore, I created outbound rules on the firewall that allows traffic over port 443 from the container instance IP towards  [the four DevOps IP adresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4#ip-addresses-and-range-restrictions).

Comment: Can you directly access Azure DevOps Server in Vnet-A via URL OR remote desktop?

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT, the client I use is outside the vnet so I can't test that nor can I use the container instance shell. I tried creating a firewall rule from the client to container instance opening up port 22 (ssh) but I am still not able to use the container shell in Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed. When the subscriptions where requested at another department, the guy forgot to say that the environment must be able to talk to internet and therefore, NAT rule was not in place. Problem solved.